# jQuery.wrap causing range error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay this is crazy.

Using jQuery 1.8.3, I want to wrap the following element in a div:

```
<div id="main" role="main">
 <h2>Item (250 x 250)</h2>
 <div id="item" style="width:250px; height:250px;background:#ccc;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

When I attempt to wrap with another simple div I get 'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' in Chrome.

```
$("#item").wrap("<div />");
```

also, in the console I fetch $("#item") it only returns one item;

Comment: I've only tested in chrome

Comment: "also, in the console I fetch $("#item") it only returns one item;"

This makes it seem like you have more than one element with the id `item`. This is a no-no, and *could* be the cause of your problem. Html ids are meant to be unique. If you have more than one `#item`, use a class instead.

Comment: That's the thing, there is only one item on the page.  It also shouldn't matter if the selector is by id or class.

Comment: The code provided works for me. Can you set up a demo that shows the issue?

Comment: I stripped out the plugin code I was working on. and sure enough it works.  So my plugin is somehow corrupting things.

Comment: It's also working for me. See jsfiddles [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nFwaZ/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nFwaZ/1/).

Comment: So could you post your plugin in use, e.g. on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: here is it an it works http://jsfiddle.net/RrEAq/

Comment: Here you go....http://jsfiddle.net/DeanIconWeb/fQv7E/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery already has a function called [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) and you are overwriting it with your own [plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/DeanIconWeb/fQv7E/).  The behavior is different from what it expects which is likely resulting in too much recursion.

Comment: Doh!  You are absolutely right. changed the name of my plugin, now it works.

Comment: Here I thought I found some crazy jQuery bug.

Answer (score 0):

**RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded:** Do you have an endless loop in your code? Can you post some more code?

if you select a DOM-element by id, there can only be one element returned.

an id is unique. if you have two elements with the same id jQuery will return two elements, BUT - not in every browser. in IE you'll get the first of both elements.

Define your own class '.item' and set class="item". Then you can correctly select more than one element.

With

```
var countOfElements = $('.selector').length;
```

you can get the count of selected elements.

Comment: in your example, you have just one elements called '#item'. there can only be one element in your selection.

Comment: I understand the restriction that there can only be id on a page.  Again, that is not the point.  My use of the id is simply for utility, my plugin (as are most(all?) jQuery plugins shouldn't care about how the elements they are applied are selected.